# While using Airflow's TriggerDagRunOperator, targeted DAG run is marked as "success" without completing child tasks

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

Using the TriggerDagRunOperator, I am able to trigger a DAG run. After a short time "running", the triggered DAG is marked as having been successful, **but the child tasks are not run.**

Additionally, I am unable to get to the context menu wherein I can manually run/clear/etc. a task instance. That is, nothing happens when I click on the triggered DAG's task instances in graph/tree view.

Some things worth noting:

- I started each of the DAGs "fresh", e.g., I cleared all records and
  deleted the DAG all-together.
- The upstream DAG start_date is the same
  as the triggered DAG's start_date, and the triggered DAG
  schedule_interval is set to None.
- I am not using a Python callable to conditionally trigger the DAG.
  The TriggerDagRunOperator task will be executed if all upstream tasks
  are completed.

I've researched this issue but cannot seem to find any good intel.
Has anyone else encountered a similar problem, and if so, can you
recommend some additional troubleshooting steps that I can take to
get this working properly?

Comment: sorry to resurrect this old post, but did you find an answer to this? I'm struggling with this at the moment

Comment: The issue is resolved, but I don't recall precisely what I did, and have since been unable to reproduce the problem. Did you change the `schedule_interval` or `start_date` for the target DAG? If so, you might consider re-versioning it (i.e. changing the `dag_id`).